# Rails times.do assign to instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the right way to do:

```
@items = 10.times.do
    Item.create(name: Faker::Name)
 end
```

Creating 10 random items and assign them to instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer above you can use `#with_object`

```
@items = 10.times.with_object([]) do |_, res|
  res << Item.create(name: Faker::Name)
end
```

or even something like this:

```
@items = Array.new(10) { Item.create(name: Faker::Name) }
```

thanks to @maxpleaner, one more solution is:

```
@items = 10.times.map { Item.create(name: Faker::Name) }
```

thanks to @engineersmnky, there are a few more solutions:

```
@items = Item.create(10.times.map { {name: Faker::Name}})
```

Comment: `10.times.map` can be used as well and is a little more to-the-point

Comment: I like @maxpleaner solution using map. Thanks!

Comment: Also `Item.create(10.times.map { {name: Faker::Name}})` and in rails 6 `Item.find(Item.insert_all(10.times.map { {name: Faker::Name}}).rows.flatten)` to insert them all at once and then retrieve them all

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Array` of `Item` objects then try this

```
@items = []

10.times do 
  @items << Item.create(name: Faker::Name)
end
```

**or**, if you want a relation then,

```
item_ids = []

10.times do 
  item_ids << Item.create(name: Faker::Name).id
end

@items = Item.where(id: item_ids)
```

**or**, if you are the only one running it for debugging purpose in development env then,

```
10.times do 
  Item.create(name: Faker::Name)
end

@items = Item.order('id DESC').limit(10)
```

Hope that helps!